Implement a header show-hide animation depending on the scroll direction in react?
The header should slide up with some animation and be hidden when scrolling down the page. When scrolling up, the header should slide down and be visible.
When scrolling up the style should be translateY(0) otherwise the DOM element should be translateY(-100px).
With the use of useEffect, useRef and window EventListener for the scroll. And also keeping track of the previous scroll position in a variable.
Below is my code, you can also view it here.
App.js


import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
/*import Header from "./components/Header";*/

const Header = () => {
  const navShowHide = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      navShowHide.current;
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          color: "white",
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: "green",
        }}
        className="headershow"
        ref={navShowHide}
      >
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{
          height: 2000,
        }}
      >
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}



styles.css


.headershow {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.headerhide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}




Is this what you wanted to do ?


const Header = () => {
  const navShowHide = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currScrollPos = window.scrollY;
      const headerSection = navShowHide.current;

      if (!headerSection) return;

      if (scrollPosition > currScrollPos)
        headerSection.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
      else headerSection.style.transform = "translateY(-200px)";

      scrollPosition = currScrollPos;
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          color: "white",
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: "green",
        }}
        className="my-transition"
        ref={navShowHide}
      >
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
.my-transition {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}





.headershow {
  transition: all 300ms;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.headerhide {
  transition: all 300ms;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}




I faced two issues with a scroll-based header update:

Class Names Not Updating on Scroll
Header Moving to the Top of the Page

This is the updated code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Header = () => {
  const [prevScrollY, setPrevScrollY] = useState(0);
  const [headerTransform, setHeaderTransform] = useState("translateY(0)");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;

      if (currentScrollY > prevScrollY) 
        setHeaderTransform("translateY(-100%)");
      else 
        setHeaderTransform("translateY(0)");

      setPrevScrollY(currentScrollY);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [prevScrollY]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        color: "white",
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: "green",
        transition: "transform 0.3s ease-in-out",
        transform: headerTransform, 
        position: "fixed",
        top: 0,
        width: "100vw",
      }}
    >
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{
          height: 2000,
        }}
      >
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


I'm strictly using useRef, so I'm looking how to do it using useRef.

I'm answering my own question. But I will keep this question open for others to share their answer.
Here is the updates inside useEffect hook.


import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
/*import Header from "./components/Header";*/

const Header = () => {
  const navShowHide = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currScrollPos = window.scrollY;
      const headerSection = navShowHide.current;

      if (!headerSection) return;

      if (scrollPosition > currScrollPos)
        headerSection.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
      else headerSection.style.transform = "translateY(-200px)";

      scrollPosition = currScrollPos;
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          color: "white",
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: "green",
        }}
        ref={navShowHide}
      >
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{
          height: 2000,
        }}
      >
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
.my-transition {
  --transition-easing-ease-in-out: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: var(--transition-easing-ease-in-out);
  background-color: #18181b;
  z-index: 9;
}



